# Not well formed json/javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting a not well formed error when working on this site and was hoping to get some help. Here is the json file I'm using. It's pretty long, but I'm getting the error in the first line of code ("product":{"). I had posted this yesterday, but people were asking for the entire code I was using.

```
{
 "product": {
        "@attributes": {
            "name": "Special Ops",
            "price": "29.9900",
            "currency": "$"
        },
        "views": {
            "@attributes": {
                "total": "2",
                "etchingMaxChars": "20",
                "defaultEtchingText": "",
                "defaultLoad": "null,lenses|858388,frames|FFFFFF,left_clip|FFFFFF,right_clip|FFFFFF,left_gas|FFFFFF,right_gas|FFFFFF,adjuster|FFFFFF,strap|FFFFFF,null"
            },
            "viewcontainer": [
                {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "name": "angledRight",
                        "type": "web/desktop",
                        "baseURLPath": "file:///C:/Users/.../goggles/specops_custom/VIEW_1_600X393",
                        "width": "600",
                        "height": "393",
                        "zoomFactor": "1.47"
                    },
                    "info": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "txt": "About Special Ops Text goes here about the goggles."
                        }
                    },
                    "view": [
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "",
                                "prices": "5.0000",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "3",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "laserEtching",
                                "dispName": "Laser Etching",
                                "options": "",
                                "maxCharacters": "20",
                                "fonts": "InterstateRegular",
                                "xPos": "0px",
                                "yPos": "-8px",
                                "svgPath": "M241.98,341.199c33.033,21.092,69.746,1.989,78.103-15.621",
                                "profanityFilterWords": ""
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "324.0000,370.0000,370.0000,366.0000,377.0000,360.0000,365.0000,321.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "2",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "lenses",
                                "dispName": "Polarized Lens",
                                "options": "Smoke,Clear,Blue,Amber|Purple|Mirror,Blue|Silver|Mirror,Smoke|Silver|Mirror,Red|Magenta|Mirror,Smoke|Red|Mirror",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/lenses/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "858388,B6ADB6,007DFA,6A4A7D,7B93AA,9E9193,DE0447,5E3343"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "339.0000,354.0000,337.0000,361.0000,370.0000,335.0000,368.0000,369.0000,392.0000,328.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "1",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "frames",
                                "dispName": "Frame",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Yellow,Clear|,Black",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/frames/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,F2D600,CFCFCF,000000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "350.0000,352.0000,348.0000,372.0000,376.0000,334.0000,364.0000,317.0000,392.0000,348.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "4",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "left_clip",
                                "dispName": "Left Frame Lock",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Black,Clear|,Yellow",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/left_clip/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,000000,CFCFCF,F2D600"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "352.0000,362.0000,348.0000,371.0000,376.0000,343.0000,352.0000,341.0000,390.0000,318.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "5",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "right_clip",
                                "dispName": "Right Frame Lock",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Yellow,Clear|,Black",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/right_clip/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,F2D600,CFCFCF,000000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "363.0000,356.0000,341.0000,377.0000,371.0000,348.0000,355.0000,370.0000,391.0000,281.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "6",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "left_gas",
                                "dispName": "Left Gasket",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Yellow,Clear|,Black",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/left_gas/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,F2D600,CFCFCF,000000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "365.0000,361.0000,340.0000,374.0000,379.0000,351.0000,356.0000,355.0000,390.0000,282.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "7",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "right_gas",
                                "dispName": "Right Gasket",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Yellow,Clear|,Black",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/right_gas/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,F2D600,CFCFCF,000000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "307.0000,316.0000,308.0000,337.0000,350.0000,281.0000,332.0000,298.0000,362.0000,234.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "9",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "adjuster",
                                "dispName": "Strap Adjuster",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Yellow,Clear|,Black",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/adjuster/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,F2D600,CFCFCF,000000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "366.0000,345.0000,344.0000,356.0000,378.0000,352.0000,368.0000,375.0000,382.0000,287.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "8",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "strap",
                                "dispName": "Strap",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Yellow,Clear|,Black",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/strap/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,F2D600,CFCFCF,000000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "",
                                "prices": "",
                                "leftNav": "false",
                                "displayOrder": "",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "background",
                                "dispName": "",
                                "options": "background",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": ""
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "name": "front",
                        "type": "web/desktop",
                        "baseURLPath": "file:///C:/Users/.../goggles/specops_custom/VIEW_2_650x252",
                        "width": "650",
                        "height": "252",
                        "zoomFactor": "1.37"
                    },
                    "info": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "txt": "About Special Ops. More text about special ops"
                        }
                    },
                    "view": [
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "",
                                "prices": "5.0000",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "3",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "laserEtching",
                                "dispName": "Laser Etching",
                                "options": "",
                                "maxCharacters": "20",
                                "fonts": "InterstateRegular",
                                "xPos": "-15px",
                                "yPos": "-58px",
                                "svgPath": "M467.503,168.446c18.426-3.05,49.64-19.418,43.423-58.752",
                                "profanityFilterWords": ""
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "324.0000,370.0000,370.0000,366.0000,377.0000,360.0000,365.0000,321.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "2",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "lenses",
                                "dispName": "Polarized Lens",
                                "options": "Smoke,Clear,Blue,Amber|Purple|Mirror,Blue|Silver|Mirror,Smoke|Silver|Mirror,Red|Magenta|Mirror,Smoke|Red|Mirror",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/lenses/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "858388,B6ADB6,007DFA,6A4A7D,7B93AA,9E9193,DE0447,5E3343"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "339.0000,354.0000,337.0000,361.0000,370.0000,335.0000,368.0000,369.0000,392.0000,328.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "1",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "frames",
                                "dispName": "Frame",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Yellow,Clear|,Black",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/frames/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,F2D600,CFCFCF,000000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "350.0000,352.0000,348.0000,372.0000,376.0000,334.0000,364.0000,317.0000,392.0000,348.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "4",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "left_clip",
                                "dispName": "Left Frame Lock",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Black,Clear|,Yellow",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/left_clip/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,000000,CFCFCF,F2D600"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "352.0000,362.0000,348.0000,371.0000,376.0000,343.0000,352.0000,341.0000,390.0000,318.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "5",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "right_clip",
                                "dispName": "Right Frame Lock",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Yellow,Clear|,Black",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/right_clip/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,F2D600,CFCFCF,000000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "363.0000,356.0000,341.0000,377.0000,371.0000,348.0000,355.0000,370.0000,391.0000,281.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "6",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "left_gas",
                                "dispName": "Left Gasket",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Yellow,Clear|,Black",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/left_gas/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,F2D600,CFCFCF,000000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "365.0000,361.0000,340.0000,374.0000,379.0000,351.0000,356.0000,355.0000,390.0000,282.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "7",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "right_gas",
                                "dispName": "Right Gasket",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Yellow,Clear|,Black",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/right_gas/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,F2D600,CFCFCF,000000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "307.0000,316.0000,308.0000,337.0000,350.0000,281.0000,332.0000,298.0000,362.0000,234.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "9",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "adjuster",
                                "dispName": "Strap Adjuster",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Yellow,Clear|,Black",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/adjuster/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,F2D600,CFCFCF,000000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "366.0000,345.0000,344.0000,356.0000,378.0000,352.0000,368.0000,375.0000,382.0000,287.0000",
                                "prices": "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0",
                                "leftNav": "true",
                                "displayOrder": "8",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "strap",
                                "dispName": "Strap",
                                "options": "White,Green,Blue,Purple,Magenta,Red,Orange,Yellow,Clear|,Black",
                                "fullAssetURL": "/strap/",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": "FFFFFF,43DC1A,007DFA,4A0999,FF0066,FF0000,FF8400,F2D600,CFCFCF,000000"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "@attributes": {
                                "inventoryAvail": "",
                                "prices": "",
                                "leftNav": "false",
                                "displayOrder": "",
                                "group": "",
                                "layer": "background",
                                "dispName": "",
                                "options": "background",
                                "id": "",
                                "colorHEX": ""
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And then this is how I am calling it using js.

```
$j.getJSON(
            "file:///C:/Users/.../specops.js",{},

            function (d) {
                $j.extend(tdata, d);
            }
        );
```

I am pretty new to working this extensively with json, etc so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas and help would be great.

Comment: Could it be that you are evaluating the JSON as JavaScript? It would interpret the brackets (`{..}`) as block and then choke on the colon. That won't work. How are you loading that file? You have to use Ajax and then parse it properly using e.g. `JSON.parse`.

Comment: looks legal to me, apart from the bits you've cut off the end.  An error in the opening tag _could_ be caused by malformed closing tags.

Comment: ye, could you post all of the code?

Comment: i'd put it through here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Beware the TRAILING COMMA OF DEATH!

Comment: I think Felix is right. I think I'm not parsing it properly. This text box won't let me put all the code for the json in because it's too long, but here is my .getJSON code. Let me know if it's just not calling correctly from there. I am still pretty new to json so I appreciate all the help! $j.getJSON( "file:///C:/Users/Ruster Sports/Documents/Rusters Site/Test/specops.js",{}, function (d) { $j.extend(tdata, d); } );

Comment: Please provide the exact error message you are receiving.

Comment: Ok, so you might just want to go back to your first question which is the same as this one, and just get all the things together? Take extra care to format your code (see below what comes from not doing so), and just keep it simple: you really should remove most of the content from your JSON, so that it still displays your error, but that it doesn't baffle us like this. I'm sure you can ignore most of the content?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with JSON and keep getting a not well formed error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616531/working-with-json-and-keep-getting-a-not-well-formed-error)

Comment: I bet this is a cross-domain/same origin policy issue since you are trying to use ajax locally, where is the HTML located?

Comment: FYI: I received a rejection for trying to improve this question: not substantial. The edit was to put the final '{' into the formatting, which would have prevented THREE now deleted irrelevant answers, and probably improved overall answers and responses to this question. Did the mods even read my suggested edit before rejecting it?

Comment: How many times are you going to ask this question? @BenParsons I fixed the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this locally and I am receiving a `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.  The problem is you can't use AJAX to access files using `file` protocol.  Host your JSON file, script and HTML on a web server like IIS or Apache and try again and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your very last object within the JSON probably has a comma after it

```
var test = {
                "product": {
                    "@attributes": {
                        "name": "Special Ops",
                        "price": "29.9900",
                        "currency": "$"
                    },
                    "views": {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "total": "2",
                            "etchingMaxChars": "20",
                            "defaultEtchingText": "",
                            "defaultLoad": "null,lenses|858388,frames|FFFFFF,left_clip|FFFFFF,right_clip|FFFFFF,left_gas|FFFFFF,right_gas|FFFFFF,adjuster|FFFFFF,strap|FFFFFF,null"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

I tried that that, and it worked fine. After "View": {} if there was a comma I got your error.